# torsocks/torify ssh doesn't work as regular user in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh, 20.04, tor

Clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04, when trying to connect as a regular user to ssh-server published in .onion, `torsocks ssh blabla.onion` I get an error:

```
WARNING torsocks[10558]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 39. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:605)</br>*
Assertion 'fclose_nointr(f) != -EBADF' failed at src/basic/fd-util.c:121, function safe_fclose(). Aborting.</br>*
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I check through `torsocks wget -qO - https://api.ipify.org; echo` as a regular user, everything is OK

When I run through `sudo torsocks ssh blabla.union` everything is OK

openssh-client/focal-updates,now 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

tor/focal,now 0.4.2.7-1 amd64 [installed]

Answer (score 4):

Problem due to file permissions `~/.ssh/config`

```
$ ls -alh ~/.ssh/

total 24K
-rw-rw----  1 ilya ilya 1.7K Aug  5 22:19 config
```

`$ chmod g-rw ~/.ssh/config`

```
$ torsocks ssh blabla.com
1596659405 ERROR torsocks[38123]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
ssh: connect to host blabla.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: `chmod g-w ~/.ssh/config` was enough for me to solve the issue on Ubuntu 20.04. I'd suggest to edit your answer though @Ilja, because it isn't obvious right away to the reader that your latest "torsocks" example is supposed to show success.